# Excel using SUMPRODUCT to find number of times a value appears in a column and in python

Tags: python, excel, list

So I have this excel sheet where there is one column and filled with 1 and 0's

[image]

the 4 represents that the maximum number of 1's in the column and I dont know how to get that number.
Iam wondering if there is a way to  get it to return something like this in excel:

[image]

So that there is a new column after the number stops repeating and it will tell you how many times it repeats.

My idea to do this with python is something like this but I am not there yet.

```
listas = [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
new_column = []
count = 1
for i in range(len(listas)):
   print(listas[i])
   if listas[i] == 1:
    
    new_column.append(count)
    if listas[i+1] == 1:
        count = count + 1
        new_column.append(count)
    # so if the first integer is 1 check the one in the next position and if 1 coninute checking until 0
```

so that the `new_column` is `[2,0,1,0,4,0]`
to return 0 or na so its just empty

How would I accomplish this in excel or python?

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach in Excel would be to use the `FREQUENCY` function:

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(MyRange,ROW(MyRange)),IF(1-MyRange,ROW(MyRange))))`

which may or may not require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, depending on your version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in B2 and fill down:
`=LET(x,IF(A2=0,SUM(A$1:A1)-SUM(B$1:B1),0),IF(x=0,"",x))`

[image]